# How do I create the YouTube "Up next" video gallery?

Tags: html, video, youtube, shopify, gallery

I'm trying to insert a "Watch next" section on my SHOPIFY website but I can't find any widgets online or any SHOPIFY plugins that have a "Watch next" style. Basically I'm trying to mimic the YouTube "Up next" section. It has a time stamp of how long the video is and when you hover over it, it gives you a small preview of the video & when you click on it, it takes you to the page the video is located.

I want a video gallery but most of the video galleries I've found play the video within the same page so It's not at all a preview, I need something that when the user click on the video, it takes them to a link. I don't really care for the "Autoplay" toggle, just as long as I can get something like this I'd be satisfied. Is there a website, widget, or code that someone knows that would give me this functionality? [image: Example]

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using a CMS, or framework? How is your site built?

Comment: I'm using a page builder plugin to create my pages so I wouldn't know which category that falls under?

Comment: With Wordpress?

Comment: Shopify actually, I know - pretty random.

Comment: You need to be more explicit as to what you want when you create a question. We can't help you unless you tell us exactly what you want, with what system and what type of code. This isn't the place to be "pretty random." Rephrase your question so other developers can help you.

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious what I want. When I said "Pretty Random" I meant a lot of people use WordPress or some other web service when creating sites such as mine.